# The cursor:pointer property doesn't apply to file upload buttons in Webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, webkit, mouse-cursor

i have CSS code that does not really work on webkit browsers such as  safari and chrome

if you want live example here it is http://jsfiddle.net/mnjKX/1/

i have this CSS code

```
.file-wrapper {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.file-wrapper input {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    -moz-opacity: 0.01;
    opacity: 0.01;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.file-wrapper .button {
    background: #79130e;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 4px 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

and this HTML code :

```
<span class="file-wrapper">
   <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
   <span class="button">Choose a Photo</span>
</span>
```

this code shows  hidden input file tag ,
the problem here is that the cursor:pointer is does not work on webkit browsers ,

how can i solve it or bypass / overtake this ?

Comment: `cursor:pointer` is working fine here.

Comment: @Quentin: Not for me. I looked at the fiddle on Chrome 14 and no pointer cursor is shown anywhere.

Comment: It appears that Chrome doesn't apply the `cursor:pointer` rule to `<input type="file">` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/mnjKX/8/

Comment: @Šime Vidas — It does, but the default value isn't `inherit` so you have to style the pointer for the input explicitly … but then it applies only to the text field part and not the button part.

Comment: I guess I have a broken Chrome build, then.

Comment: Chrome 14.0.835 (Win) not working.

Comment: @Quentin The [`cursor` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor0) does inherit by default, it's just that it's unable to inherit all the way to the button inside the `<input type="file">` element. That button is unreachable and its presentation cannot be defined with CSS.

Comment: @Šime Vidas — I edited your JS Fiddle. With the code you wrote, pointing at the text field part of the input shows the default cursor, if I change it so that it sets `cursor: pointer` on the input itself, then it shows the pointer cursor.

Comment: @Šime Vidas — Not one I saved. I just stuck `cursor: pointer` in a rule-set with a selector that matched the input.

Comment: @Quentin I think I've figured it out. The `cursor` property indeed **is** inherited, but the browsers override it on form controls. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/mnjKX/20/

Comment: @Quentin For instance, Chrome's user agent style sheet defines a rule with this selector `input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="file"] ::-webkit-file-upload-button, button` for which the `cursor` property is set to `default` (overriding the inherited `pointer` value)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For starters, it works in Chrome if you remove the  `height` declaration from the `input` rule.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mnjKX/16/

But this transparent input field is a hell of a hack... I wouldn't rely on it.

---

**Update:**

And here is the proper solution:

```
::-webkit-file-upload-button { cursor:pointer; }
```

I thought the file upload button is unreachable, but Chrome's user agent style sheet proved my wrong `:)`

Comment: @Mor It's just too hackish. I don't see my answer as a complete solution.

Comment: Very nice, you can also reverse the button with -webkit-rtl-ordering:  left;

Comment: You can't reach the button in other browsers. So the proper solution in fact is not proper enough. +1 for the hackish solution though. It's probably the best hack out there.

Comment: @user732456 The question specifically addressed Webkit browsers. I didn't look for solutions for other browsers. It could be that there exist similar solutions for those other browsers.

Comment: Cool 
::-webkit-file-upload-button { cursor:pointer; } solved my problem

Answer (score 17):

An interesting (cross-browser) solution I came up with:

Give the input a CSS property of cursor:pointer, place the input in a div (with overflow:hidden) and give the input a left padding of 100%. The padded area will have the pointer property.

I personally don't trust -webkit and -moz fixes because I feel like they are arbitrary and temporary, and will be replaced soon.

Comment: Very nice solution. I happen to have my input wrapped in its own form, so this works like a charm, no extra div required :)

Comment: clever. i'm always super paranoid about nuances like this suddenly changing for no reason

Answer (score 3):

```
input[type='file']{
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

<input type="file">
<img width="24" height="24" title="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

cursor:pointer does not work on input file just because of the default button. No special reason here. You need to remove its appearance via this code, pay attention with font-size:0.

It works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and IE for me. I hope, this will also help you.