# Cursor Pointer doesn't work in Web-Kit Browsers

Tags: html, css, file-upload, webkit, cursor

I have file-uploader control.

When i hover on button in Web-Kit browsers, cursor is default, while must be pointer.

I red this post **[The cursor:pointer property doesn't apply to file upload buttons in Webkit browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554845/the-cursorpointer-property-doesnt-apply-to-file-upload-buttons-in-webkit-brows)** but in my case i don't use property `height`. Also try solution that @Mohammed Ibrahim suggest, but it also doesn't work for me.

Here is my example : **http://jsfiddle.net/q686cc7s/4/** I try to add `cursor:pointer` for every possible selector, but no success.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

---

If set `display:none` for `input` then cursor works correctly but uploader - not :)

Comment: just try #button:hover{cursor:pointer;}

Comment: @Stefan, i try it. Result still the same http://jsfiddle.net/q686cc7s/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this always did it for me

```
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Weird, because i try it also before your answer and it doesn't work.